# Matplotlib: One X-Axis with two x labels of different type (int and string) in bar chart with one Y-Axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am running through a problem on how to produce the attached image in `matplotlib`. I have `n` X-Axis (Users' most active minute) values in `x1` and corresponding `n` Y-axis (Count) values. I can do the bar chart using these two axes. However, I have another variable `Date` which I want in the upper X-Axis (`x2`) exactly like the attached image. The important point is both `x1` and `x2` is of same length and as you can see the datatype of `x1` is `int` and `x2`'s datatype is datetime(/string).

`x2` is **NOT** derived from `x1` and the **position** of both the ticks and labels of `x1` and `x2` would be same. In brief, you can say X-Axis having two different labels with same Y-Axis. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I would like to have the Y-Axis `Count` in the middle of each bar.

**P.S:** It would be nice if generic answer is provided as I have more than 5 datapoints unlike the attached image. So, **I need a solution for n number of x1, n number of x2, and n number of Y values**. Thank you!

[image: This is what I am looking for]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import datetime as dt

n = 15 

dates     = pd.date_range(start="2022-09-24 09:00",periods=n,freq="30T")
dates_str = [idate.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M') for idate in dates]

count= np.random.randint(low=300,high=1200,size=n)
ids =  np.random.randint(low=2000,high=10000,size=n)


X = range(n)
Y = count

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()


width = 0.65 # the width of the bars 
ax1.bar(X, Y, width, color="#fa0872")
for i, v in enumerate(Y):
    ax1.text(i, v*0.6, str(v), color='k',ha="center" )
    
ax1.set_xticks(X)
ax1.set_xticklabels(ids)

ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax2.set_xticks(X)
ax2.set_xticklabels(dates_str,rotation = 45,ha='left', rotation_mode='anchor')

ax1.set_xlabel(r"User id")
ax1.set_ylabel(r"Count")
ax2.set_xlabel(r"Date")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated for the answer. However, I need a suggestion as you run the example for 15 points, it looks nice I would need it for 100 points. What changes would you suggest if I want to convey the same information through the plot so that it does not look odd. Here you see, it already does not look so good for only 35 points due to large dates and count can't be accommodated inside. Looking forward to your suggestion. The plot with 35 data points => [Link](https://pasteboard.co/6IYtAL0BgJC8.png) @Li Yupeng

Comment: If you want to display 100 pieces of data, I don't think you can tweak it to make it look good. Several methods can be tried, but there is no guarantee that they will work. 1) Make the canvas bigger; 2) Reduce the number of ticklabels.